# SQL Copied query from MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to recreate a MS Access query in SQL, the following is the Access query converted to run in SQL

```
    SELECT Column1
          ,Column2
          ,Column3
          ,Count('x') AS CountX
    FROM [SchmaName].[SQLView]
    WHERE ("SomeWhereStatement")
    GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3
    HAVING Count('x')>1;
```

What I am confused about is the

```
 ,Count('x') AS CountX
```

and

```
 HAVING Count('x')>1;
```

X does not come from the SQLView that has been created and when I run the above it will return a single record with Columns 1 - 3 being null and column CountX being 12896. I am expecting this return about 4285 records in total and I suspect the reason that I am not is something to do with this Count. Any suggestions as to what this count is actually doing?

Comment: Using `count('x')` is no different than using `count(1)` or `count(*)` -- it's just counting literal strings (albeit a very odd way).  Are you sure you have values for the other columns you are grouping by?  It sounds like they are all `null` thus aggregating to a single result.  Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: The query seems to look for duplicates `HAVING Count('x')>1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass any constant argument in `COUNT()` (i.e. 'x' is constant argument), it will return total number of records  :

So, with your query it will return the records based on Columns which are defined with `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Count('x') AS CountX
FROM [SchmaName].[SQLView]
WHERE ("SomeWhereStatement")
GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3
HAVING Count('x') > 1;
```

Comment: Ok thanks, this explains what it is doing and points me in the right direction